# Convert JSON Plus JSON Schema into raw HTML?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I've found a lot of solutions that use on-the-fly scripting to convert JSON and JSON-Schema's to a human-readable form.

What I need, however, is a way to produce the ***raw*** HTML without any dynamic elements on the ***server side***.

This form will need to be a ***read-only*** HTML view of the JSON object.

#### Options#1:

1. Take a JSON-Schema and convert it to a pure HTML template.
2. Store the pre-generated HTML Template.
3. Then, for each JSON I pass it and the template to a method (maybe w/ some css).
4. And finally get raw HTML.

#### Option#2:

1. Store the JSON-Schema.
2. Pass the JSON-Schema and the raw JSON to a method (maybe w/ some css).
3. And finally get raw HTML.

Comment: It would help if you could post what the HTML output would look like given a JSON Schema

Comment: Any HTML will do as long as it's predictable and can be 508 compliant, really. However, I was thinking ***<label ...>*** and ***<input ...>*** tags would be the easiest to work with for the 508 compliance. And the information should be nest-able. The schema or some other definition will need to be able to handle syntax to specify the type/value of input/label field or whatever is used.